# android split zip file and make a file

Tags: java, android, file, zip

I want to download couple of zip file parts from the server (file1.z01, file1.z02, file1.z03 etc.)

Now after download all the parts, can we merge these parts into a zip through the code and make a zip file?

Comment: so you want to download files and combine them to a zip file..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this just change the values accordingly...

```
import android.util.Log; 
import java.io.BufferedInputStream; 
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream; 
import java.io.FileInputStream; 
import java.io.FileOutputStream; 
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry; 
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream; 


public class Compress { 
  private static final int BUFFER = 2048; 

  private String[] _files; 
  private String _zipFile; 

  public Compress(String[] files, String zipFile) { 
    _files = files; 
    _zipFile = zipFile; 
  } 

  public void zip() { 
    try  { 
      BufferedInputStream origin = null; 
      FileOutputStream dest = new FileOutputStream(_zipFile); 

      ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(dest)); 

      byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER]; 

      for(int i=0; i < _files.length; i++) { 
        Log.v("Compress", "Adding: " + _files[i]); 
        FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(_files[i]); 
        origin = new BufferedInputStream(fi, BUFFER); 
        ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(_files[i].substring(_files[i].lastIndexOf("/") + 1)); 
        out.putNextEntry(entry); 
        int count; 
        while ((count = origin.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) { 
          out.write(data, 0, count); 
        } 
        origin.close(); 
      } 

      out.close(); 
    } catch(Exception e) { 
      e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 

  } 

}
```

Comment: Its only adding those file into a zip file but i have to make a zip file from those zip file parts. I simply divided my zip file into parts and uploaded on the server. now i want to download these parts files in the my app and rebuild/merge back in to the zip file into the app.

Comment: do u know how to download files from server ?? just asking

Answer (score 0):

[Zip4j](http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/) has a convenient method to merge split zip files.

```
ZipFile.mergeSplitFiles(File outputZipFile)
```

will merge all the split zip files into one zip file specified with `outputZipFile`

Lets say you have split zip files: ZipFileName.z01, ZipFileName.z02, ZipFileName.z03.....ZipFileName.zip code below will merge them to MergedZipFile.zip

```
import java.io.File;

import net.lingala.zip4j.core.ZipFile;
import net.lingala.zip4j.exception.ZipException;

public class MergeZipFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("ZipFileName.zip");
            zipFile.mergeSplitFiles(new File("MergedZipFile.zip"));
        } catch (ZipException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```